# Add an advert into a list of Jekyll posts

Tags: jekyll

I'm looking for a way to do something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="post"></li>
    <li class="ad"></li>
    <li class="post"></li>
    <li class="post"></li>
    <li class="post"></li>
</ul>
```

Generating the list of posts isn't a problem for me, it's injecting the `li.ad` into that list of posts.

Currently, I've got the basic for loop returning all of my posts:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
<li class="post">
    <h1><a href="{{ post.url }}" title="{{ post.title }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
    <p>{{ post.summary }}</p>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to work perfectly - big thanks to [Dave Rupert](http://twitter.com/davatron5000) for his help.

```
{% for post in site.posts %}

    <li class="post">
        <!-- post stuff -->
    </li>

{% if forloop.first %}

    <li class="ad">
        <!-- ad stuff -->
    </li>

{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

`for` loops have a `forloop` variable that can track the index, so you can do something like this:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% if forloop.index == 2 %}<li class="ad"><!-- ad stuff --></li>{% endif %}
  <li class="post"><!-- post stuff --></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding - it wasn't quite right though. See my answer for the correct approach.

Comment: @user1912818: Ah, right. A post was skipped. I updated the answer, for posterity.

Comment: Also this will only add the advert if there are two items, I'm sure most people would want the advert after the first post regardless of the existence  of a second post.